# 言わない vs 言わなくない - A negative verb conjugated as an adjective?

Tags: usage, conjugations, i-adjectives

While reading a text in Japanese, I came across the phrase "何も言わなくなったから".

I don't understand what the ～くない stands for. As far as I know it is used as the negative of an adjective... but 言う is a verb! It's like 言わない (the negative form of 言う) was used as an i-adjective.  Any thoughts?

Comment: by " I came up with the phrase " do you mean "  I came across the phrase "?  please give more context for the quote, ie, the surrounding dialogue. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretical adding of ない:

- 言う (plain)
- 言わない (negative)
- 言わなく・ない (negative+negative)
- 言わなく・な**か**った (negative+negative+past)

Therefore 言わなくなった does **not** come from another ない.

- 言わない→言わなく→言わなく・なる→言わなく・なった

The adverb 言わなく modifies the verb なる in past tense.

Comment: my goodness!! it was in front of me all the time.. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: so does "何も言わなくなったから" mean " because (subject) didn't say anything" --({subject} came to the state where  {subject} did not say anything) ?

Comment: *Stopped* talking. *Fell* silent. Said nothing *further*. Something like that... Don't lose the nuance of なる, which is that previously he was in some other state than 何も言わない and then なる'd to that state.

Comment: kudos on that なる'd coinage (¬‿¬)

Comment: @Macarena: Could you share the context? I am curious to know how this was used. It sounds like "after a while he stopped objecting everytime [something happend] and said nothing so [something carried on regardless]".